# How to Remove Outer Layer of JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to remove the outer (parent) layer of a JSON file so that I can process it, however I have no idea how.

As you will see by the code below, the outer 2 most layers are 2 dictionaries, however, python says the 2nd dictionary ("item") is just a string when I call its type. Am I incorrect in how I interpret the structure?

```
sample_object6 = {
    "items":
        {
            "item":
                [
                    {
                        "id": "0001",
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Cake",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0002",
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Raised",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ]
                    },

                    {
                        "id": "0003",
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Old Fashioned",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0004",
                        "type": "bar",
                        "name": "Bar",
                        "ppu": 0.75,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ],
                        "fillings":
                            {
                                "filling":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "7001", "name": "None", "addcost": 0 },
                                        { "id": "7002", "name": "Custard", "addcost": 0.25 },
                                        { "id": "7003", "name": "Whipped Cream", "addcost": 0.25 }
                                    ]
                            }
                    },

                    {
                        "id": "0005",
                        "type": "twist",
                        "name": "Twist",
                        "ppu": 0.65,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                            ]
                    },

                    {
                        "id": "0006",
                        "type": "filled",
                        "name": "Filled",
                        "ppu": 0.75,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ],
                        "fillings":
                            {
                                "filling":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "7002", "name": "Custard", "addcost": 0 },
                                        { "id": "7003", "name": "Whipped Cream", "addcost": 0 },
                                        { "id": "7004", "name": "Strawberry Jelly", "addcost": 0 },
                                        { "id": "7005", "name": "Rasberry Jelly", "addcost": 0 }
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
                ]
        }
}
```

I thought that it might be possible to store the nested portion starting at the first list (right after 'item') in a variable and then work with this but if I can't get python to see that item is a dictionary inside the item**s** dictionary, then I fear I am at a loss with how to proceed.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

As far as the processing goes, there has been none because I could not even get the string to read as a dictionary appropriately.

This is what I tried to test if it was a dictionary:

```
for i in sample_object6:
    print(i + str(type(i)))
    for n in i["item"]:
        print(n + str(type(n)))
```

Comment: Give more code about how you have processed. Can't get the reason with data's structure alone

Comment: Did you try `sample_object6["items"]["item"]`?

Comment: @PM2Ring I did so in a for loop in an attempt to iterate through key - value pairs. After reading your comment, it surprisingly worked as I originally thought it should have. I greatly appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

After submitting the same code that I thought I had already submitted, I noticed that python is interpreting the object correctly. I have some obvious fundamental gaps in how to work in python and I'm sorry I took it to the forum.

For the record (and for future python newbies out there like me), I used the following code which returned the proper class types:

```
#this returned a class type of dictionary
print(type(sample_object6["items"]))
#this returned a class type of list
print(type(sample_object6["items"]["item"]))
```

Thank you SungJin Steve Yoo & Pm2Ring for your help.